# NSFetchedResultsController -> How to implement sections?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, sections, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am having trouble getting sections with a NSFetchedResultsController working. I have an entity, say 'Employee' and a string attribute, let's say 'name'. Now I want to show all employee's names in a UITableView using a NSFetchedResultsController... no problem, heres my Code:

```
if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:@"name" cacheName:@"root"];

    NSError *error;
    [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

But the NSFetchedResultsController creates a section for each entity. So when I have 200 employees, it creates 200 sections. Why?

And how do I implement those methords properly:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
   return [[_fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     // Return the number of rows in the section.
     return [[[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = [[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

May I do understand the whole concept wrong? Where is the difference between [_fetchedResultsController sections] and [_fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles]?

I hope you can help me and thanks in advance!

EDIT: I forget to tell you the most important thing: I want to have sections separated by the first letter of the 'name' attribute. (Like the Music-APP).

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `nil` as your `sectionNameKeyPath` when initializing your NSFetchedResultsController.

If you pass `name`, you basically say "please create one section for each name". When passing `nil`, you tell it to create only a single section.

You tableview method implementations look right to me.

`[_fetchedResultsController sections]` gives you an array with objects that you can ask for things like the number of objects in a section. In contrast, `[_fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles]` is mostly so you can tell the `NSFetchedResultsController` which section titles to use (i.e you would set this to an array with one string for each section). In your case, you can just ignore it.

Comment: Hi, thank you! But I forget to tell you that I want sections like in the music-app. (I want to use the first letter of the name as the section title). So how do I do that? Sorry about the bad english. =)